# Flash Scope msgs do not show up with immediate=true buttons

Tags: jsf-2, myfaces

I have the following button:

```
<h:commandButton action="#{handler.actionDelete}" value="Delete" immediate="true"/>
```

As part of the handler.actionDelete, I am adding a message to Flash Scope.

```
public String actionDelete() {
this.service.delete(this.bean);
FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getFlash().put("infoMessage","OK");
return "NextPage?faces-redirect=true";
```

}

I do not see the flash messages on the next screen when I press the command button. I will see the message if immediate is set to false.

I'm using MyFaces 2.1.8.

Any ideas?

Thanks,
Luis

Answer (score 0):

I can reproduce your problem. It's likely a bug in MyFaces. You need to [report](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/MYFACES) it to MyFaces guys.

It works fine in Mojarra 2.1.12.